# The set of non-negative reals is closed

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

In the proof for the question below. I don't understand why do we get $\frac{c}{2} < c$ I don't understand how we reached this conclusion given that $a_n$ and $b_n$ are $c/2$ seperated[image]. Can someone explain this part?

Comment: You don't under stand why if $c > 0$ that one half of $c$ will be less than all of $c$?

Comment: I guess $\frac c2<c\iff 0<\frac c2\iff 0<c$

Comment: I don't understand why given that $|a_n - b_n|$ are $\frac{c}{2}$ separated then why do we get $\frac{c}{2} < c$?

Comment: If $b_n \le -c$ and $a_n > 0$ then $|b_n + a_n| > c$.  So $|b_n + a_n| \not < \frac c2 < c$.

Comment: Yeah. That is perfect. Thank you.

Comment: They arent trying to say that because they are $\frac c2$ seperated that therefore $\frac c2 < c$.  They are saying that because $\frac c2 < c$ and that therefor they are $\frac c2$ separated.

Comment: Yeah I see. That makes sense.